# Pausing a HTML5 Audio element causes the entire file to be downloaded

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio

I have the situation where there is a page with many Audio elements on it, some of which are very long (up to ~2 hours). In essence, they are being created and controlled as such:

```
var a = new Audio();
a.preload = 'metadata';
a.src = 'long-track.mp3';

a.play();
```

When it plays, the browser (Chrome, in this case) correctly makes a range request and the server returns a "206 Partial Content", for what looks like about 2 minutes of data at a time. After the ~2mb of data is loaded, it stops requesting data. So far so good. Then, this is executed:

```
a.pause();
```

This causes the browser to download the entire remainder of the file. (!!?!~@!!!?) Obviously, this can be a problem if the user decides to listen to the first couple of seconds of a few tracks: they'd start downloading *gigabytes* of unwanted data.

I've seen some other questions asking [how to force the full file to be buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764015/how-can-i-force-an-html5-audio-element-to-buffer-an-entire-song), but I actually want the exact opposite.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an official function that does this, though there should be, but it seems the general consensus is that the following code is the best way to do what you want

```
a.src = '';
a.load();
```

jPlayer [implements this method](https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer/blob/master/jquery.jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js#L1954) to stop audio buffering. The only problem is, [there may be cross-browser problems](http://blog.pearce.org.nz/2010/11/how-to-stop-video-or-audio-element.html) with this method. Failing any of this you could maybe try removing the audio element from the page, have you tried that?

Comment: Do you know how it might work when the user wants to unpause?

Comment: Once you do this, that particular <audio> playback cannot be resumed. 
I suppose this would only be feasable if you had your own GUI for the audio elements, instead of using the native <audio> player.
You may be able to create resume functionality by: noting the time when it was stopped, then on resume: creating a new audio element, and starting playback from the previous time.